# How can I space out the native position of draggable elements using flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, draggable

How can I space out the native position of draggable elements using flexbox?

I have `justify-content: space-evenly` applied to `"container1"`. However, it doesn't look like this has any effect due to the absolute positioning or Javascript draggable positioning.

Basically, I want to spread these `draggable` div elements out on page load rather than being stacked.

Is this possible with flexbox?

Here is the HTML snippet:

```
  <div class="container1">

    <div id="draggable1">
      <div id="draggableheader">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557912410-2e6a13bcc09e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="">
        <p>Drag me</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="draggable2">
      <div id="draggableheader">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595660038837-03f3832841da?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="">
        <p>Drag me</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="draggable3">
      <div id="draggableheader">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595515769499-0f61fc8db2e9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="">
        <p>Drag me</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

CSS snippet:

```
.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#draggable1,
#draggable2,
#draggable3 {
  position: absolute;
}

#draggable1 img,
#draggable2 img,
#draggable3 img {
  width: 20vw;
}

#draggable1 p,
#draggable2 p,
#draggable3 p {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.15;
}

#draggableheader:hover,
#draggableheader:hover,
#draggableheader:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
  transition: .35s;
}
```

Draggable elements JavaScript:

```
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable1"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable3"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
      // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
      document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
      // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
      elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }
  
    function dragMouseDown(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
      // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
      document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }
  
    function elementDrag(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      // calculate the new cursor position:
      pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
      pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      // set the element's new position:
      elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
      elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }
  
    function closeDragElement() {
      // stop moving when mouse button is released:
      document.onmouseup = null;
      document.onmousemove = null;
    }
  }
```

Also, here is the Codepen: https://codepen.io/john-szetho/pen/dyGxQdW

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used another div to be the parent of the "container1" divs. So the display flex worked on those divs and not directly on the one you need the position to be absolute. I also added a height, but this shouldn't interfere (I was seeing how the background-color applied). I also added flex to "container1" but that's up to you and how you want do position those images. So it was possible for me with flexbox but I had to add a few things. Hope it helped, let me know. :)

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable1"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable3"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
      // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
      document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
      // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
      elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }
  
    function dragMouseDown(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
      // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
      document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }
  
    function elementDrag(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      // calculate the new cursor position:
      pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
      pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      // set the element's new position:
      elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
      elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }
  
    function closeDragElement() {
      // stop moving when mouse button is released:
      document.onmouseup = null;
      document.onmousemove = null;
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: .85rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #313131;
  padding: .5rem;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -0.15;
}

.sml {
  font-size: .85rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
.container1 {
  width: 33%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-outside {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#draggable1,
#draggable2,
#draggable3 {
  position: absolute;
}

#draggable1 img,
#draggable2 img,
#draggable3 img {
  width: 20vw;
}

#draggable1 p,
#draggable2 p,
#draggable3 p {
  text-align: center;
/*   margin-top: -1vw; */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.15;
}

#draggableheader:hover,
#draggableheader:hover,
#draggableheader:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
          transform: scale(1.15);
  -webkit-transition: .35s;
  transition: .35s;
}

.margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Draggable HTML element test</h1>
  <h2><span class="sml">¶</span>DIV id="draggable"</h2>
  <h2><span class="sml">¶</span>Nested DIV id="draggableheader"</h2>
  <h2 class="margin-bottom"><span class="sml">¶</span>Hover transform: scale 1.15 + transition time .35s</h2>
  <div class="container-outside">
    <div class="container1">
      <div id="draggable1">
        <div id="draggableheader">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557912410-2e6a13bcc09e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="">
          <p>Drag me</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <div id="draggable2">
          <div id="draggableheader">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595660038837-03f3832841da?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="">
            <p>Drag me</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <div id="draggable3">
        <div id="draggableheader">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595515769499-0f61fc8db2e9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="">
          <p>Drag me</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @claricetorres this works well. I also managed to solve this by adding "container" divs and adding "position: relative" then changing the left position to 33.33% and 66.66%. https://codepen.io/john-szetho/pen/LYGwMxQ

Yours is probably more efficient as it manages to do this using flexbox.

Comment: It's interesting how "container" has to have a set pixel height (300px in your snippet) for the flexbox to register its vertical positioning. When "height: 300px" is removed the flexbox seems to default to the top of the page. Any ideas why? Cheers

Comment: I think it's beacuse of the position: absolute. If you remove the height and remove the position absolute it should be displayed bellow the <h2>. But you need to use this absolute to have the drag working. I always set heights to divs as I go so I didn't even notice. This doc explains about how the position absolute behaves: [css-absolute](https://devdocs.io/css/position)